# 535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted with G Suite and Django

Tags: django, gmail, google-workspace

I'm trying to send email from my G Suite account. I have enabled 2FA and generated an app password that I'm using in my django project.

My `settings.py` file looks like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv("EMAIL_USER")

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv("EMAIL_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
```

I have set the `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` as the 16 character generated app password. Why is it still failing?

(There is no way to allow "less secure apps" with G Suite if I got 2FA enabled - I'm just redirected to creating an app password, which is what I have done)

I just keep getting

```
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 29sm2220422ljv.72 - gsmtp')
```

What setting am I missing?

Comment: is `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ` the string you use to login to `EMAIL_HOST_USER ` 's Gmail inbox? it should be.

Comment: you should set EMAIL_PASSWORD environment variable and not EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD

Comment: It says `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` in docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/

Comment: @panchicore yes it is

Comment: but you did set it to os.getenv("EMAIL_PASSWORD") so you should set EMAIL_PASSWORD, check it with -> printenv EMAIL_PASSWORD

Comment: What do you mean? in my .env file I got EMAIL_PASSWORD=<app_password_here>

I am getting the password printed correctly

Comment: did you try to unlock Captcha
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563

Comment: Have you looked into xoauth2 https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol

Comment: @iklinac yeah I tried clicking the next and going through the steps - no success

Comment: @DaImTo - feels a bit over the top to that set up? It should work as is with app passwords..

Comment: Well if you look around you will notice that recently a llot of people are getting the same error you are.  It has me wondering if Google has stealth locked out client login on the smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to use SMTP with a gsuite account before but my steps to get it to work with a normal gmail account are as follows.

Just a thought though have you tried using a service account with the Gmail api instead?

## Less secure apps

Have you allowed for less secure apps?  Please do so, and see if that helps.  [Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

## Clear Captcha

[Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

## 2fa use an app password.

If using 2 Step Verification in Gmail, you may need an application  password. [Create & use App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

[image: Use "recent" mode if you are using POP3 on multiple devices. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en]

## Xoauth2

If it still doesnt work you may need to consider checking [xoauth2-protocol](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What's weird is that if I use my private gmail and set up an app password, it works fine, but with G Suite, it just won't work